# Don't render if array is empty - Angular *ngFor

Tags: json, angular

I'm building up a Frontend with JSON Data.
I have to go trough a lot of arrays to check if a value exists inside. If the Value doesn't exist, then my complete HTML shouldn't render.

```
<ng-container *ngIf="document161['_source']['161_Events']">
                      <div class="row">
                        <span class="col-md-auto meta-object text-muted"><span>Begräbnistag:</span></span>
                        <span class="col">
                          <span *ngFor="let event of document161['_source']['161_Events']">
                            <span *ngFor="let sub of event.peventsub">

                              <ng-container *ngIf="sub.content === 'Begräbnis'">
                                <span *ngFor="let geburtsort of event.pstdatetypesub">
                                  {{geburtsort.content}}
                                </span>
                              </ng-container>

                            </span>

                          </span>
                        </span>
                      </div>
                      <mat-divider class="my-2"></mat-divider>
          </ng-container>
```

What i have already tried is:

```
<ng-template #thenBlock>
<ng-container *ngIf="document161['_source']['161_Events']">
                          <div class="row">
                            <span class="col-md-auto meta-object text-muted"><span>Begräbnistag:</span></span>
                            <span class="col">
                              <span *ngFor="let event of document161['_source']['161_Events']">
                                <span *ngFor="let sub of event.peventsub">

                                  <ng-container *ngIf="sub.content === 'Begräbnis'">
                                    <span *ngFor="let geburtsort of event.pstdatetypesub">
<ng-container ngIf="*ngIf="geburtsort.content; then thenBlock else elseBlock">
                                      {{geburtsort.content}}
</ng-container>
                                    </span>
                                  </ng-container>

                                </span>

                              </span>
                            </span>
                          </div>
                          <mat-divider class="my-2"></mat-divider>
              </ng-container>
</ng-template>
<ng-template #elseBlock>

</ng-template>
```

But as you can see there are multiple problems. Maybe Ii can't reach the ngIf condition if the value doesn't exist. And the then else logic doesn't work inside a ng-container template.

What should be the best solution?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
*ngIf="document161?._source?.161_Events?.length > 0"
```

If array having values it will show that element else will hide same.

Comment: important are the geburtsort.content values. So its possible that document161['_source']['161_Events'] exists. But there will be no geburtsort.content values.